# Bx-slider multiple slider custom controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, bxslider

I am using the bx-slider plugin to build multiple sliders on a single page. Each slider has a class name associated with it and custom prev/next buttons. Please note they are not unique. This is because the page is dynamic. I am confused on how to initiate the slider so that the custom next/prev buttons only toggle the slides closest to the buttons. Here is what i am thinking:

```
<div class="slider">
    <a class="prev" href="#">prev</a>
    <ul>
       <li>Slide 1</li>
       <li>Slide 2</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
</div>

<div class="slider">
    <a class="prev" href="#">prev</a>
    <ul>
       <li>Slide 1</li>
       <li>Slide 2</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why you wish to have custom controls? and not the default one?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the list of sliders in an array. Whenever your custom controls are clicked, you can find out the closest '.bxslider' class and find it index in the entire page. Using that index, you can call the slider object from the array and invoke the prev or next events.

```
  var slider_array = new Array();
  $('.bxslider').each(function(i){
     slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({controls:false});
  });


  $('.bxslider-controls a').bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if($(this).hasClass('pull-left')) {
      var obj = $(this).parent().parent().find('.bxslider');
      var index = $('.bxslider').index(obj);
      slider_array[index].goToPrevSlide();  


  } else if($(this).hasClass('pull-right')) {
    var obj = $(this).parent().parent().find('.bxslider');
      var index = $('.bxslider').index(obj);
      slider_array[index].goToNextSlide();  
  }

});
```

Added jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/atgshbnv/